# How to call a class and setState in one onClick(ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm pretty new to React and I was wondering how I could call a function inside a class (so like this.handleChange) and an arrow function with a setState inside within one onClick of a button.

I've tried using commas and && in between the 2 lines of code.

```
<button name="Plus" onClick={() => this.setState({ Operator: 'plus' }) && this.handlePlus}>+</button>
```

The above code is inside the render and return.

The expected result is that the code calls the function and changes the state.Instead it just changes the state(so only does the first part).

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: you can pass a second argument to the`setState` function -> `this.setState({ Operator: 'plus' }, this.handlePlus)`

Comment: `this.setState()` returns `undefined` so it's a falsy value; replace `&&` with `||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState()` has an optional second parameter that is a function that will be invoked once the state has been set. You could do:

`this.setState({ Operator: 'plus' }, this.handlePlus);`

You can also use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(this.state.Operator === 'plus' && prevState.Operator !== 'plus') {
    this.handlePlus();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
< button name = "Plus"
onClick = {
  () => this.setState({
    Operator: 'plus'
  }, () => this.handlePlus())
} > + < /button>

this would work fine.or
if you are looking
for something like this....
you can handle multiple buttonClick event like this

  <
  button name = "Plus"
value = "yourValue"
onClick = {
  this.handleChange
} > + < /button>

handleChange = (e) => {
  const {
    name,
    value
  } = e.target;
  switch (name) {
    case 'Plus':
      this.setState({
        [name]: value
      });
      break;
    default:
      //enter code here
      break;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `this.setState({ Operator: 'plus' }` within the `handlePlus` function.